# Critical Edges and Bottleneck Edges in a Flow Network (Max-Flow/Min-Cut Problem)

Tags: algorithm, network-flow, minimum-cut

A critical edge in a flow network `G = (V,E)` is defined as an edge such that decreasing the capacity of this edge leads to a decrease of the maximum flow. On the other hand, a bottleneck edge is an edge such that an increase in its capacity also leads to an increase in the maximum flow in the network. Are all critical edges also bottleneck edges? I am having trouble proving this or giving a counterexample.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Hi, this question is probably better suited for our sister site [math.SE]. It’s not about programming or debugging, so it’s not a great fit here. Over there, the crowd is more knowledgeable about this on average than over here, so you’ll get better answers faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nope

Consider a simple graph: 1 -> 2 -> 3 in which both edges have the same weight. Both of these edges are critical, but neither is a bottleneck.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you! By the way, as a follow up, can we always find a bottleneck edge in a graph? Intuitively, it seems like not always - as an example, I am thinking about an instance where the min-cut is not unique.

Comment: @John In fact, the above graph does not have a bottleneck.

Comment: Are you confident in this? A critical edge $e=(u,v)$ is defined to be an edge such that in the residual graph of the max flow, $u$ is reachable from $s$ and $v$ is reachable (after reversing the edges) from $t$, in the above graph, neither is a critical edge... as well as neither are bottleneck edges.